# How returning reference and const reference are different?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, return-type

The particular example could be the return type of the operator function to overload assignment operator.

```
const className& operator=(const className&)
```

```
className& operator=(const className&)
```

What is the difference between the above two?

Comment: You cannot assign to or call a non-const method from a const reference. So for instance `(x = y) = z;` would be illegal with the const version of your example.